# Quantized coefficients of Chern-Simons action and F $\wedge$ F $\wedge \dots$

Tags: string-theory, topological-field-theory, quantization, chern-simons-theory

We know that for U(1) gauge field Chern-Simons action in 2+1 Dim(ension), we have an action
$$
S=\alpha \int A \wedge dA
$$
with $\alpha=k/(4\pi)$ for a proper level quantization. Here $k$ is **the level** of the theory.

For U(1) gauge field  action in 3+1 Dim(ension), we have an action
$$
S=\alpha \int F \wedge F
$$
with $\alpha=\theta/(4\pi)$ (or $\alpha=\theta/(2\pi)^2$?) for a proper coefficient. **However, the $\theta$ needs not to have level quantization.**

> Q1: How about other odd $(d+1)$-simensional spacetime Chern-Simons action:
>   $$
> S=\alpha \int A \wedge dA \wedge dA \wedge \dots
> $$
>   what is $\alpha=$? for a proper level quantization? Is this $\frac{k}{2(2\pi)^{d/2}}$?

-

> Q2: How about other even $(d+1)$-simensional spacetime Chern-Simons action:
>   $$
> S=\alpha \int F \wedge F \wedge  \dots
> $$
>   what is $\alpha=$? for a proper coefficient? (**However, the $\theta$ needs not to have level quantization.**) Is this $\frac{\theta}{(2\pi)^{(d+1)/2}}$?

- If you use any Ref, please do share with me. Thank you.

Comment: Edit: $\theta$ needs not to have level quantization. But what is the proper coefficient for U(1) field?

Answer (score 2):

At least for even dimensions the normalization is that $$S = \frac{(i/2\pi)^n}{n! }\int \operatorname{tr} F^{\wedge n}$$ is an integer. I learned this from *Gauge Fields, Knots, and Gravity* by Baez and Muniain. They do not give a proof but you can find one in *From Calculus to Cohomology* by Madsen and Tornehave. Since the odd dimensional case is a surface term for the even dimensional case I believe that the normalization is the same but I am not entirely sure about this.